# Can you have a sustainable community when the topic is "questions about anything"?

Tags: discussion, area-51

I just read [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/why-cant-you-have-just-one-site/).  The following quote sticks out:

> There is no (good) community that can
> form around “let’s just talk about
> everything and tag it".

To be honest this sounds like a hypothesis.  In fact, this blog post provides no evidence to support this hypothesis.  So let's be scientific and make some!   There is the [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/),  so why not create an "everything group".  If it sinks then the hypothesis is proven,  end of story.  If it succeeds,  then you get a larger userbase.  What do you have to lose?

Comment: Go for it: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create

Comment: @Jon Seigel Done: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14571/everything

Comment: Followed...this could be the next Yahoo! Answers...or something more epic.

Comment: And the countdown to "How is babby formed?" begins.

Comment: @gnovice  added,  so that was like 45 seconds.

Comment: Okay, wth, I'm in for lolz

Comment: @The Rook: 54 seconds, not bad.

Comment: Duplicate: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6623/everything-else (had everyone forgotten it was already proposed? really?)

Comment: Not only that, that one was a duplicate of a now deleted one

Comment: @Juan Manuel  So then your saying that people want this.

Comment: @the, whatever I'm saying, just follow the one that already exists instead of creating a new one.

Comment: @Juan: `everything` is obviously not a duplicate of `everything else`.

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche  No,  because everything goes in one category and then everything else goes in the other.

Comment: @Juan Manuel Okay,  this is exactly my point,  no one has proved that this is a bad idea.  You must approach these things with science.

Comment: I would say that Yahoo Answers, answers.com, allexperts.com, wikianswer, askville, answerbag, yedda, and the hundreds of other generic "answer" sites have proven that this is a bad idea.

Comment: @aar: But they all had a major flaw: They took themselves seriously.

Comment: @Aarobot  I think the downfall of these communities is the software that drives them. SO is a great code base and I think it would benefit people.

Comment: @Aarobot also some of thoughs communities are pretty popular,  and popular==money.

Comment: Do you honestly believe that ALL of those answer sites failed to build a solid community simply because their software had a few flaws?  History has proven that even the crappiest software can be successful if it fulfills an important social requirement (Napster).  And it's really just basic anthropology and psychology that people gravitate toward the like-minded and aren't particularly interested in being part of a group that isn't united by a common thread.  I'm sure that some of those sites are "popular" in the sense of random hits, but we are trying to build communities of *experts*.

Comment: @Aarobot I guess that depends on your definition of failure.   Its a failure to me because I don't use it.  But it is successful in generating review and there for if SO isn't the one to build it someone else will.   Someone will captivate on this, i see this as a matter of business and science not a matter of emotion.

Comment: "If SO isn't the one to build it someone else will" - except somebody else already *has*.  SEIS is trying to carve out a niche for itself, not copy sites that are already out there; it is indeed a matter of business and straying from your (working) business model when there's still so much fertile ground to cover *within* the model does not make good business sense.  And please, chill with the language; I didn't vote to close anything, not that it would justify the outburst even if I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Aarobot's answer is so darn good I'm just going to *steal it!*

> I would say that [Yahoo Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/), [answers.com](http://www.answers.com/), [allexperts.com](http://www.allexperts.com/), [wikianswer](http://wiki.answers.com/), [askville](http://askville.amazon.com/Index.do), [answerbag](http://www.answerbag.com/), [yedda](http://yedda.com/), and the hundreds of other generic "answer" sites have proven that this is a bad idea.

I'll add that we were (and continue to be) stunned how *many* of these Q&A sites there are on the internet when we were doing our initial Stack Overflow project research. And bear in mind that **answers.com is a top 200 website** (!).

http://www.alexa.com/search?q=answers.com

The Q&A format clearly has strength, but these sites are all doing it wrong in our estimation -- by repeating exactly the mistake in your question. When sites are about "everything" then they are about nothing.

Who knows, maybe we're wrong, but a loose confederation of sites strongly dedicated to specific topics, with vibrant communities around that topic, is the way I know based on experience and also feel in my heart to be correct.

So that's what we have to do.

Comment: I don't think either of you are doing it *wrong*, per se, just *differently*.  I think that for your average clueless tube jockey asking prosaic "how is babby formed?" questions where you don't care what kind of person answers or what they say, the everything-goes philosophy is great.  By restricting the subject matter to professional- or at least enthusiast-level questions and answers, you practically guarantee that you'll never be competing for the same market space.  I'd be very surprised if there's *any* intersection between Stack Exchange and Yahoo Answers communities.